# Ad-hoc adding claims to a signed in identity user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I want to "impersonate" a user in my asp.net core app - as a feature for support staff, so that they can effectively be logged in as a user to troubleshoot issues.

Before .net core, in asp.net MVC5, we had this working like this:

```
var impersonatedUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

var impersonatedIdentity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(impersonatedUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
//add the claims to allow us back to the current user and to flag that we're impersonating:
impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserImpersonationKey, bool.TrueString));
impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.OriginalUserIdKey, _currentUser.User.Id.ToString()));

//log in the impersonated user:
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
//log us out:
authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, impersonatedIdentity);
```

This would nicely create an identity for the user we wanted to impersonate, add some claims  to tell the app we're impersonating, and then sign in as that user. The claims would be added to the cookie, making it all persistent.

I'm trying to do this now in ASP.NET core, and not having much luck. How can get a user, sign in as that user, and then add some claims for that user.

I'm aware there are ways to add claims to a user when they log in, such as providing a custom `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` as [described here](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) - but that adds claims to all users, and I only want to add claims to the user when I'm entering impersonation.

My code thus far:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());

await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, "Cookies");

// Now if I could just add some claims to the user to flag we're in impersonation mode....
```

Comment: ...not surprised no one answered. It is now 4 months later and I still cant find a valid tutorial on how to accomplish this. Did you get it figured out?

Comment: @dinotom Answer incoming...

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`.

Here's some code:

```
 var principal = await _claimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);

  // Now add some claims to that
  ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Some Key", "Some value"));

  // In my case, I want to sign out the current user and use this new principal with "extra" claims
  await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
  await HttpContext.SignInAsync(Authentication.CookieScheme, principal,  new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties 
    {
        IsPersistent = false
    });
```

And my factory is injected into my controller:

`IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsPrincipalFactory`

Comment: ...Thanks, I started on that route, by reading that blog post, but see my issue in this question ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293292/code-changes-to-register-claimstransformer-in-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: ...I see now, in Core 2.0 that's probably gone because you can use DI. 2 Questions, Why are you using HttpContext.SignInAsync instead of the sign in manager method? and What library is Authentication.CookieScheme from I cannot find it.